# Reaction between n-butylithium and either an aromatic bromide or an alkylbromide

Tags: organic-chemistry, organometallic-compounds

What exactly happens? Does the butylithium chain add to the carbon where the bromine is attached? or do the 2 undergo halogen metal exchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite a long time that I did myself, but I used BuLi to transmetalate. *I.e.* $\ce{MesBr + BuLi -> MesLi + BuBr}$

Answer (score 0):

Coupling BuLi with an alkylbromide to extend an alkyl chain is an extremely minor produt.  Transmetalation or elimination products will dominate.